# React Router Param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

Is it possible to do this with react router?

```
<Route path="/:reset_password" component={ResetPassword} />
<Route path="/:create_password" component={CreatePassword}/>
```

I want use different param with different component. I test above code and it doesn't work. the code above work if I change to this:

```
<Route path="/something1/:reset_password" component={ResetPassword} />
<Route path="/something2/:create_password" component={CreatePassword}/>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Not sure why you put those as parameters? Why not just `path="/reset_password"` and `path="/create_password"` (without the `:`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chris said, remove the colons and/or assign dedicated routes. React Router can't differentiate between the two routes you've supplied, as they're technically identical (root path + a dynamic parameter.)